# International loan repayment

Tags: personal-loan

What are the reporting requirements when I receive a large wire transfer (approx $170,000) from an acquaintance in Russia? She is sending this money as repayment of a loan. Also, are there any tax implications?

Comment: Do you have a contract detailing the loan amount, rate, and time?

Comment: You use "$", are you in the USA?

Comment: Tax questions require a country tag.